# json.net deserialization return null

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string into a C# object. When I trap in the debugger, the JSON visualizer appears to be parsing the string just fine. However, when I push the string through the following code, the object returned has null values for the properties.

Here's my code:

```
    public static Item GetPrices(string itemStr)
    {
        Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(itemStr);
        return item;
    }

    public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "prices")]
        public Prices Prices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prices
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "priceUofM")]
        public PriceUofM[] PriceUofMs { get; set; }
    }

    public class PriceUofM
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uofm")]
        public string UofM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

and here's what I'm passing to it:

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "1A50CC070S",
        "prices": 
        [
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "BOX",
                    "price": "$81.11"
                }
            },
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "CASE",
                    "price": "$811.11"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've run it through several online parsers, and all of them appear to be interpreting the JSON string just fine. What am I doing wrong in formatting the string to cause JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to fail?

Comment: Your outmost object has only one property: item. Not id or prices so the deserializer doesn't find anything to do. You could paste the JSON as classes in Visual Studio or use an online class creator, there are other differences also in your classes compared to the JSON, for example prices is an array whereas in your code it isn't.

Comment: So I need to pull the  id and prices out like this?

    {
        "id": "1A50CC070S",
        "prices": 
        [
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "BOX",
                    "price": "$81.11"
                }
            },
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "CASE",
                    "price": "$811.11"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: @J.Hochberg check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this json:

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "1A50CC070S",
        "prices": 
        [
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "BOX",
                    "price": "$81.11"
                }
            },
            {
                "priceUofM": {
                    "uofm": "CASE",
                    "price": "$811.11"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

C# model would be:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prices")]
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    [JsonProperty("priceUofM")]
    public PriceUofM PriceUofM { get; set; }
}

public class PriceUofM
{
    [JsonProperty("uofm")]
    public string UofM { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

In order to deserialize the string into an Item object, JSON string would be something like:

```
{
    "id": "1A50CC070S",
    "prices": 
    [
        {
            "priceUofM": {
                "uofm": "BOX",
                "price": "$81.11"
            }
        },
        {
            "priceUofM": {
                "uofm": "CASE",
                "price": "$811.11"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks. I see what I was missing, and appreciate you taking the time. I did change the name of the Price property on PriceUofM to ItemPrice avoid it hiding the Price class.